# PHP Sort an array by numerical name

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Creating a site using Codeigniter. I have used codeigniters directory helper to get the filenames of all files in a directory:

`$this->load->helper('directory');
$files = directory_map('directory_name/', 1);`

This all works as expected and I get a list of the files in the directory - print_r($files) proves this.

However, the file names all start with numerical values:

```
 1_firstfile.doc  
  2_nextfile.doc  
  3_another.exe  
  ...   ...  
  11_thisfile.txt  
  12_filename.pdf
```

My problem is that the files are returned in a different order that I would like. I wish them to be returned in the order above, but instead they are returned like this:

```
 1_firstfile.doc    
  11_thisfile.txt  
  12_filename.pdf  
  2_nextfile.doc   
  3_another.exe
```

Obviously, they are being returned in alphabetical order, but I need them returned in numerical order.

I have tried `$files = sort($files,1)` but that seems to just empty the array.
So, apart from changing the filename, how can I get the array to arrange them in the order I require?

Comment: line 1 = sort($files); line 2 print_r($files); You do not need to assign a sort to a var

Comment: use natsort() for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) functions are "pass by reference", so it actually modifies the argument directly, returning a success or failure status, so

```
$files = sort($files)
```

sorts `$files`, but then assigns the success status (a Boolean true/false) to `$files`

Simply do

```
sort($files)
```

Note that to sort cleanly by the numeric part of the filename, you should be using [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) with the `SORT_NATURAL` flag, or [natsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)